# Invoking a Multi-Threaded DLL at Run-Time

Tags: winforms, dll, task-parallel-library, async-await, c#-5.0

All, I call a .NET DLL containing a WinForm at run-time from a WinForm C# application. To do this I use the following:

```
DLL = Assembly.LoadFrom(strDllPath);
classType = DLL.GetType(String.Format("{0}.{1}", strNamespaceName, strClassName));
if (classType != null)
{
    if (bDllIsWinForm)
    {
        classInst = Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
        Form dllWinForm = (Form)classInst;
        dllWinForm.Show();

        // Invoke required method.
        MethodInfo methodInfo = classType.GetMethod(strMethodName);
        if (methodInfo != null)
        {
            object result = null;
            result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInst, new object[] { dllParams });
            return result == null ? String.Empty : result.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

This is invoking the WinForm DLL and the required method fine for serial methods within the DLL. However, I am now invoking a multi-threaded DLL, and calling the following method:

```
public async void ExecuteTest(object[] args)
{
    Result result = new Result();
    if (!BuildParameterObjects(args[0].ToString(), args[1].ToString()))
        return;
    IProgress<ProgressInfo> progressIndicator = new Progress<ProgressInfo>(ReportProgress);
    List<Enum> enumList = new List<Enum>()
    {
        Method.TestSqlConnection, 
        Method.ImportReferenceTables
    };
    Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        foreach (Method method in enumList)
        {
            result = Process.ProcessStrategyFactory.Execute(Parameters.Instance, progressIndicator,
            Process.ProcessStrategyFactory.GetProcessType(method));
            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                // Display error.
                return;
            }
        }
    });
    await task;
    Utilities.InfoMsg("VCDC run executed successfully.");
}
```

But this is returning control to the caller right away due to the `await` (which is expected). However, the return causes the calling method to exit which closes the DLL WinForm.

**What is the best method to keep the DLL WinForm active/open?**

Thanks for your time.

---

*Edit. Following the suggestion by Stephen below I have decided to turn my DLL intery method type to `Task<object>` and set up a continuation as follows*

```
if (classType != null)
{
    if (bDllIsWinForm)
    {   
        // To pass object array to constructor use the following.
        // classInst = Activator.CreateInstance(classType, new object[] {dllParams});
        classInst = Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
        dllWinForm = (Form)classInst;
        dllWinForm.Show();

        // Invoke required method.
        MethodInfo methodInfo = classType.GetMethod(strMethodName);
        if (methodInfo != null)
        {
            object result = null;
            result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInst, new object[] { dllParams });
            if (result != null)
            {
                if (result.GetType() == typeof(Task<object>))
                {
                    Task<object> task = (Task<object>)result;
                    task.ContinueWith(ant =>
                        {
                            object innerResult = task.Result;
                            return innerResult == null ? String.Empty : innerResult.ToString();
                        });
                }
                return result.ToString();
            }
            return String.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

*I decided to set up the continuation instead of the `await` to avoid the chaining that would occur with the `await` keyword - that is making the calling method (that calling the DLL of type `Task<String>` etc. up the call stack.*

*The DLL entry method now becomes:*

```
public Task<object> ExecuteTest(object[] args)
{
    Task<object> task = null;
    Result result = new Result();
    if (!BuildParameterObjects(args[0].ToString(), args[1].ToString()))
        return task;
    IProgress<ProgressInfo> progressIndicator = new Progress<ProgressInfo>(ReportProgress);
    List<Enum> enumList = new List<Enum>()
    {
        Method.TestSqlConnection, 
        Method.ImportReferenceTables
    };
    task = Task.Factory.StartNew<object>(() =>
    {
        foreach (Method method in enumList)
        {
            result = Process.ProcessStrategyFactory.Execute(Parameters.Instance, progressIndicator,
            Process.ProcessStrategyFactory.GetProcessType(method));
            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                // Display error.
            }
            task.Wait(5000); // Wait to prevent the method returning too quickly for testing only.
        }
        return null;
    });
    return task;
}
```

*But this causes the DLL WinForm to be show for a split second and then disapear. i even attempted to make the `Form dllWinForm` global to keep the refernce to the object active, but this also has not worked. I want to note that the call to the DLL (**N.B. the calling method is already running on a background thread-pool thread**).*

*Any further helps is appreciated.*

Comment: Trying not to kick in an opened door: don't close it.  Boilerplate is BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted and TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext to run code on the UI thread once the worker is done.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean @HansPassant. Thanks for your time...

Comment: @HansPassant BackgroundWorker is more or less obsolete and considered legacy. It doesn't do anything more than a simple call to Task and Progress, can't provide detailed progress asynchronously, can't be used to chain multiple asynchronous calls, can't use the ThreadPool, can't take advantage of asynchronous methods, cant ...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - BackgroundWorker uses the ThreadPool, through the SynchronizationContext class. Its progress is also reported using the ThreadPool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to guess what you have in dll but eventually your dll code +  exposed in your question:

```
dllWinForm.Show();
```

should eventually have been after juxtaposing:

```
new Thread
      (   
         () => new Form().ShowDialog()
       )
       .Start();
```

Probably, you should change `dllWinForm.Show();` by `dllWinForm.ShowDialog().Start()`;

`ShowDialog()`, in contrast with `Show()`,  [starts its own message pumping and returns only when explicitly closed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39wcs2dh%28VS.80%29.aspx).

**Update (in respnse to comment):**
It is not absolutely necessary to launch a form from UI.
Since you are on .NET 4.5, it is probably simpler to use WPF (instead of Windows Form) form.
Here is [the code for WPF form](http://reedcopsey.com/2011/11/28/launching-a-wpf-window-in-a-separate-thread-part-1/)  which, in order to adjust for Windows Form,  you should change `Dispatcher` parts by initializing [WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext.aspx)

Though, IMO, WinForms code will be much more complex.

Comment: +1 How I eventually sorted this was to make sure that the DLL was invoked from the UI thread. Then the multi-threaded DLL was invoked as I had it. Thanks very much for your time.

Answer (score 4):

Change the return type of `Execute` to `Task` and `await` it.

Comment: +1 Good idea, but how can I do that from the caller without making the calling code non-generic? The called is a user invoked function to call their own DLLs. Sorry I should have mentioned that! Thanks for your time.

Comment: I can't see how something like `if (typeof(result) == GetType(Task)) await result as Task;` will ever work here?

Comment: If the type of the result is (or is derived from) `Task`, then you can cast it to `Task` and `await` it.

Comment: Hi Stephen I have attempted your suggestion and would appreciate any further advice you may have. I have edited the question to show what I have tried. The DLL WinForm is still showing and then rapidly disappearing as the calling method returns. Thanks very much for your time...

Comment: You're still not `await`ing the returned `Task`. You set up a continuation and then return (and I assume you're closing the form on return).

Comment: But setting up a continuation is exactly what await will do. I am not `Close()`ing the form on the return from the invoked method either.`await`ing in this case is just going to cause me to have to use the `async` methods up the call stack, this complicates things. Any help would be appreciated, as I am getting in a muddle with this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: When is the form closed? What closes it?

Comment: At this point I assume that it is going out of scope when the calling method returns. But as I said before, I have made the form global and it is still getting closed. I have checked for thrown exceptions an there are none...

Comment: In that case, I'd say the first step is finding out why the form is closing. Try adding a close handler, stick a breakpoint in there, and check out your stack.