# How to program wait Custom MessageBox OK,Cancel,Yes,No responses?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, parallel-processing, windows-phone-8, task-parallel-library

How to program wait Custom MessageBox OK,Cancel,Yes,No responses? i have been using custom messageBox because of my natural language because messagebox has only english ok,yes,no i have found this one: [Customizing MessageBox on Windows Phone 7](http://cloudstore.blogspot.com/2011/01/customizing-messagebox-on-windows-phone.html)

```
private MessageBoxService CustomMsgBox= new MessageBoxService();

public async void Handle(RecordRequest message)
{
    AutoResetEvent waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
         CustomMsgBox.Closed += CustomMsgBox_Closed;
         CustomMsgBox.Closed += (s, e) => waitHandle.Set();
         CustomMsgBox.Show(
         "Login Please! ",
         "Kayıt",
         MessageBoxServiceButton.OKCancel);
    });

    waitHandle.WaitOne();

    // Must Wait MessageBox Ok or Cancel like Normal MessageBox!!!
    Login.IsOpen= true;

    // do something ...
}

void CustomMsgBox_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.CustomMsgBox.Closed -= this.CustomMsgBox_Closed;
    string rst = this.CustomMsgBox.Result.ToString();

}
```

Normally wp8 messagebox is locked while clicking OK-Cancel. But My Costom MessageBox is not waiting. How to lock my CustomMsgBox until clicking ok-Cancel.

SAMPLE USAGE:

```
private PixelLab.Common.MessageBoxService _service = new PixelLab.Common.MessageBoxService();
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this._service.Closed += this.MessageBoxService_Closed;
    this._service.Show(
     "test",
     "alo!",
    MessageBoxServiceButton.OKCancel);

    //if (_service.IsOpen == true)
    //{
    //    MessageBoxResult rslt = _service.Result;
    //    if (rslt == MessageBoxResult.No)
    //    {
    //        MessageBox.Show("işlem iptal edildi");
    //    }
    //    else
    //    {
    //        MessageBox.Show("işlem onaylandı");
    //    }
    //}
}

private void MessageBoxService_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this._service.Closed -= this.MessageBoxService_Closed;
    string rst  = this._service.Result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Can't you use a Childwindow class and call it instead of the messageBox?

Comment: So you want to have the popup prevent access to the parent object and don't know how to do it, or you don't want to do that and can't get it working given that change?  It's not clear what you want it to be doing in the end.  Note the fact that you're blocking the UI thread is a clear indication that something is wrong; that's not the solution you'll want to go with.

Comment: I would have used for a "Messagebox" a modal (using `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()`) [WinForm in a separate thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459102/invoking-a-multi-threaded-dll-at-run-time/16552000#16552000)

Comment: Have you tried the Windows Phone Toolkit which provides a CustomMessageBox? http://phone.codeplex.com/